# How this entry has been erased from this file?

Tags: c, file, record, procedural-programming

-this function is responsible for erasing an intended entry that exists in a file by checking if the account NO of it exist or not. here exists two files the first one called "record" that contains the original data and the second one called "new" which the data of "record" will be copied in it, and as you can see from the code that if the account NO does not exist, the data will be copied from "record" to "new" and it will be renamed to "record", and if it exist the record will be deleted, and thus the two files will be closed and the "record" file will be removed.

-What i do not understand is how the entry has been deleted, where in the else statement the data hasn't been copied to "new" file and after that the "record" file has been removed. which seems to me that the "new" should be "void", but it contains the remaining records and the intended entry has been deleted.

**-How the entry has been deleted?**

**-How the data has been copied to the "new" record which will be renamed to "record" without printing it in the else statement?**

**#note:**
-the struct variable "add" is used in another function that stores the entry's account NO.

```
struct data
 {
   int acc_no;
   char name[30];
   int age;
 } add,rem;


   void erase(void)
  {
      FILE *old,*newrec;
      old=fopen("record.txt","r");
      newrec=fopen("new.txt","w");

      printf("Enter the account no. of the customer you want to delete:");
        scanf("%d",&rem.acc_no);

        while (fscanf(old,"%d %s %d",&add.acc_no,add.name,&add.age)!=EOF)
         {
             if(add.acc_no != rem.acc_no)

             {
                  fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d",add.acc_no,add.name,add.age);
             }

             else
             
               {
                  printf("\nRecord deleted successfully!\n");
               }
         }

       fclose(old);
       fclose(newrec);
       remove("record.txt");
       rename("new.txt","record.txt");`
```

Comment: strange `fprintf(newrec,"%d %s %d",add.acc_no,add.name,add.age);` should have a newline in the format string or age and acc_no are going to be merged

Comment: And `while (fscanf(old,"%d %s %d",&add.acc_no,add.name,&add.age)!=EOF)` is prone to an infinite loop should the input not match the expected format.

Comment: @AndrewHenle when EOF is reached the while loop will end.

Comment: @JhonathanMartini EOF will never be reached if `fscanf()` fails to convert any fields, returns `0`, and never reads any more - it will keep retrying and failing to read the same data over and over.

Answer (score 0):

It simply copies every record  except the one to delete from `record.txt` to `new.txt`.

It then removes the old `record.txt` and renames `new.txt` to `record.txt`.

Comment: i understand this process but, how it copies it where it is not mentioned in the else statement?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The `fprintf` that would copy the record into the other file is not executed if the record number is the one to remove.

Comment: @JhonathanMartini I'm also unsure exactly what you don't understand, but... if you have a pile of magazines, and want to get rid of issue 23, you can move them one-by-one to a new pile. When you get to #23, instead of putting it in the new pile, _you have to do something else with it_ (put it in a different pile, throw it in the trash) before you pick-up the next one. However, data is not the same as a magazine. If you don't write it somewhere (by calling `fprintf`) you can just leave it where it is (in the `add` structure)... when you go round and read the next record, it will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks @TripeHound your explanation what i was looking for, now i got it ;)